# How to set MongoTemplate Collection Mapping

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch, spring-mongo

I have a DAO called `Foo`.  [`MongoTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) wants to map this to the database collection named `foos`.  The problems are:

- In Mongo, the collection is named `Foos`.
- The `Foo` object comes from a third-party library and all its constructors are `private`.

How do I configure my Spring Beans such that `MongoTemplate`--via a [`MongoItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.html)--knows the collection `Foos` maps to my Document `Foo`?

If it helps, I'm primarily concerned with reading data *from* MongoDB.

Comment: The `MongoItemReader` wraps the call `MongoOperations#find(Query query, Class<?> type)`.  Are you saying that you really need the `MongoOperations#find(Query query, Class<?> type, String collectionName)`?  If so, that would be something SB would need to add.

Comment: @MichaelMinella: Yeah, one workaround was extending `MongoTemplate` and exposing the method that allows `collectionName`.  I'm not sure why they didn't expose that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: I ended up extending `MongoItemReader` and adding a getter/setter for `collection`.  This allowed me to delegate the stuff I didn't care about, and modify `doPageRead()` to set the collection in my custom query:

```
@Scope("step")
public class MyMongoItemReader extends MongoItemReader<Object> {

    public void setCollection(String collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    @Override
    protected Iterator<Object> doPageRead() {

        ...
        Query mongoQuery = // set query
        ...

        return (Iterator<Object>) //
           template.find(mongoQuery, Object.class, this.collection).iterator();
    }

}
```